# virtual file set column and rowset variable U-SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, u-sql

I'm having an issue with scheduling job in Data Factory.
I'm trying to approach a scheduled job per hour which will execute the same script each hour with different condition.

Consider I have a bunch of Avro Files spread in Azure Data Lake Store with following pattern.
/Data/SomeEntity/{date:yyyy}/{date:MM}/{date:dd}/SomeEntity_{date:yyyy}*{date:MM}*{date:dd}__{date:H}

Each hour new files are added to Data Lake Store.
In order to process the files only once I decided to handle them by help of U-SQL virtual file set column and some SyncTable which i created in Data Lake Store.

My query looks like following.

```
DECLARE @file_set_path string = /Data/SomeEntity/{date:yyyy}/{date:MM}/{date:dd}/SomeEntity_{date:yyyy}_{date:MM}_{date:dd}__{date:H};
@result = EXTRACT [Id] long,
....
date DateTime
FROM @file_set_path 
USING someextractor;

@rdate =
    SELECT MAX(ProcessedDate) AS ProcessedDate
    FROM dbo.SyncTable 
    WHERE EntityName== "SomeEntity";

@finalResult = SELECT [Id],... FROM @result
CROSS JOIN @rdate AS r
WHERE date >= r.ProcessedDate;
```

since I can't use rowset variable in where clause I'm cross joining the singe row with set , however even in this case U-SQL won't find the correct files and always return all files set.

Is there any workaround or other approach ?

Comment: Should it be "WHERE date **==** r.ProcessedDate;"?

Comment: no because I'm trying to process all files after last processed date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also please note that file sets cannot perform partition elimination on dynamic joins, since the values are not known to the optimizer during the preparation phase.

I would suggest to pass the Sync point as a parameter from ADF to the processing script. Then the value is known to the optimizer and file set partition elimination will kick in. In the worst case, you would have to read the value from your sync table in a previous script and use it as a parameter in the next.

Answer (score 3):

I think this approach should work unless there is something not quite right somewhere, ie can you confirm the datatypes of the `dbo.SyncTable` table?  Dump out `@rdate` and make sure the value you get there is what you expect.

I put together a simple demo which worked as expected.  My copy of SyncTable had one record with the value of 01/01/2018:

```
@working = 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ( (int)1, DateTime.Parse("2017/12/31") ), 
            ( (int)2, DateTime.Parse("2018/01/01") ),
            ( (int)3, DateTime.Parse("2018/02/01") )
     ) AS x ( id, someDate );


@rdate =
    SELECT MAX(ProcessedDate) AS maxDate
    FROM dbo.SyncTable;

//@output =
//    SELECT *
//    FROM @rdate;

@output =
    SELECT *, (w.someDate - r.maxDate).ToString() AS diff
    FROM @working AS w
         CROSS JOIN
             @rdate AS r
    WHERE w.someDate >= r.maxDate;


OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

I did try this with a filepath (full script [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ce1cec2716d47bbfadd993b77821b2f)).  The thing to remember is the custom date format H represents the hour as a number from 0 to 23.  If your SyncTable date does not have a time component to it when you insert it, it will default to midnight (0), meaning the whole day will be collected.  Your file structure should look something like this according to your pattern:

`"D:\Data Lake\USQLDataRoot\Data\SomeEntity\2017\12\31\SomeEntity_2017_12_31__8\test.csv"`

I note your filepath has underscores in the second section and a double underscore before the hour section (which will be between 0 and 23, single digit up to the hour 10).  I notice your fileset path does not have a file type or quotes - I've used `test.csv` in my tests.  My results:

[image: Results]

Basically I think the approach will work, but there is something not quite right, maybe in your file structure, the value in your SyncTable, the datatype etc.  You need to go over the details, dump out intermediate values to check until you find the problem.

Comment: Did you check it with virtual file set column and what is you directory pattern?

Comment: do you have other files for example files with pattern more than month ago ?
and could you filter out them by your query ?

btw the last part of the pattern is file name not folder, and my files does not contain any extension, anyway i don't think it will make any impact

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the gist of wBob's full script resolve your issue?  Here is a very slightly edited version of wBob's full script to address some of the issues you raised:

1. Ability to filter on SyncTable,
2. last part of pattern is file name and not folder.  Sample file and structure: `\Data\SomeEntity\2018\01\01\SomeEntity_2018_01_01__1`

```
DECLARE @file_set_path string = @"/Data/SomeEntity/{date:yyyy}/{date:MM}/{date:dd}/SomeEntity_{date:yyyy}_{date:MM}_{date:dd}__{date:H}";

@input =
EXTRACT [Id] long,
        date DateTime
FROM @file_set_path
USING Extractors.Text();

// in lieu of creating actual table
@syncTable = 
SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES
    ( "SomeEntity",     new DateTime(2018,01,01,01,00,00) ), 
    ( "AnotherEntity",  new DateTime(2018,01,01,01,00,00) ), 
    ( "SomeEntity",     new DateTime(2018,01,01,00,00,00) ), 
    ( "AnotherEntity",  new DateTime(2018,01,01,00,00,00) ), 
    ( "SomeEntity",     new DateTime(2017,12,31,23,00,00) ), 
    ( "AnotherEntity",  new DateTime(2017,12,31,23,00,00) )
    ) AS x ( EntityName, ProcessedDate );

@rdate =
SELECT MAX(ProcessedDate) AS maxDate
FROM @syncTable
WHERE EntityName== "SomeEntity";

@output =
SELECT *,
       date.ToString() AS dateString
FROM @input AS i
     CROSS JOIN
         @rdate AS r
WHERE i.date >= r.maxDate;


OUTPUT @output 
TO "/output/output.txt"
ORDER BY Id
USING Outputters.Text(quoting:false);
```